How to flash the Yocto to the hardware without SD-Card interface
My target platform uses VAR-SOM-MX8M-PLUS System on Module(SoM) from Variscite/NxP, we intend to run the Yocto software on the SoM. We would like to flash the Yocto image to the internal flash/eMMC and boot from that image.
Our target platform will not have SD-Card interface, however we will have Usb and Ethernet interfaces to the SoM. SoM also has the JTAG Debug/trace interface.
Is it possible to flash the Yocto image through USB or Ethernet interfaces to SoM internal memory eMMC/Flash?
Understanding the possibilities of flashing Yocto image to the SoM.

uuu software from nxp

Yocto Project is a build system, you don't want to flash a build system to hardware. You should flash an image like any other image built by any other build system. As mentioned above, for NXP you can use uuu. Once you have running system with self-update support, you can update it via any other supported interface by system itself.

First you need to install uuu.
Then, you need to check your board flash mode and the right USB port for it, and then you can check your board presence with:
uuu -lsusb

then you can flash the eMMC with your Yocto image, example:
sudo uuu -b emmc_all core-image-base-imx8mm-lpddr4-evk.wic

For more information check: Flashing Linux BSP using UUU
